# ArgumentException while passing CommonFileQuery to StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync()

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to read a set of `StorageFile` from a `StorageFolder` using the `GetFilesAsync()` method in Windows Phone 8.1 RT.
The method works fine if only files are to be retrieved, but throws an `ArgumentException` when any `CommonFileQuery` is passed to sort the files.
I want to retrieve the files sorted by creation date, so I pass `CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate`, but I get the following stacktrace:

```
Value does not fall within the expected range.
at Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery query)
at FileGetters.FileGetterMethods.<GetMyFilesAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
```

How can I get a sorted list of all the files present in the particular folder ordered by date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry to tell you that apparently, `CommonFileQuery` can only be used for Library Folders.

> System.ArgumentException: You specified a value other than DefaultQuery from the CommonFileQuery enumeration for a folder that's not a library folder. Check the value of query

Source: [MSDN.com](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/BR211591.aspx)

Library Folders can be accessed using the class `KnownFolders` (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(Windows.Storage.KnownFolders);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-WindowsPhoneApp,Version%3Dv8.1);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true))

But here is what you CAN do:

```
IEnumerable<StorageFile> files = await myFolder.GetFilesAsync();
IOrderedEnumerable<StorageFile> orderedFiles = files.OrderBy(f => f.DateCreated);
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up using. But what are library folders? Are they the folders created by the OS itself, like `KnownFolders`?

Comment: According to MSDN, yes. I will edit my answere accordingly, thanks for the Input!